# I am getting an invalid ARN from Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have an issue where I am not getting the **instance-profile** in the ARN path. Code snippet:

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "launch-template" {
  image_id      = data.aws_ami.ecs.id
  instance_type = "c5.large"
  iam_instance_profile {
    arn = aws_iam_role.ecsInstanceRole.arn
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecsInstanceRole" {
  name               = "assess-instance-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role_policy.json
}
```

I get the following error:

**Error: error creating EC2 Launch Template (lt-12344444444444) Version: InvalidIamInstanceProfileArn.Malformed: The ARN ‘arn:aws:iam::1234444444444:role/assess-instance-role’ is not valid. The expected format is arn:aws:iam:::instance-profile/** (this is followed by < instance-profile-name > but the formatting it not letting me write it.

I am on the following version:

```
Terraform v1.2.3
on darwin_arm64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.75.2
```

Comment: You can't attach a role to an ec2, you must create an instance profile from the role. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_instance_profile

Comment: That did it! Thanks a bunch. Please write this as a formal answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jordanm pointed out in the comment, you can't attach a role to an ec2, you must create an instance profile from the role: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_instance_profile